# Is it possible to use variables inside 'fetch' options?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have a working code:

```js
fetch("https://api.url.com", {
  body: "{\"search\":\"Search String\"}",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer <token>",
  },
  method: "POST"
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Is there a way to use variable instead of the "Search String"?

I was trying something like `` "{\"search\":\"`${variable}`\"}" ``, but unfortunately this does not work. I'm a little bit stuck. Help, please!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? The whole string needs to be surrounded by the backticks to be a template string, you can't start one in the middle of a regular string. `JSON.stringify({ search: variable })` is going to be far more robust than using template strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both your solutions are working great! Now I feel stupid... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string templates:

```js
const value = "Some value"
fetch("https://api.url.com", {
  body: `{\"search\":\"${value}\"}`,
/* ... */
```

or you can use `JSON.stringify` method:

```js
const value = "Some value"
fetch("https://api.url.com", {
  body: JSON.stringify({ search: value }),
/* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks, Evgeny! This solves my issue: both your solutions are working well! Thanks once again.